# Is there a way to load faster which BackColor = transparent controls in C# WinForm?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, performance, user-interface

i'm just working on a project that i need to use 30~35 checkboxes in form and  i have to set a custom background image for main form and the all checkboxes on it. But all must have to transparent backcolors when i set them to transparent in designer, form loads with flickers, i already tried `DoubleBuffered = true` and

```
   protected override CreateParams CreateParams
   {
       get
       {
           CreateParams CP = base.CreateParams;
           CP.ExStyle |= 0x02;
           return CP;
       }
   }
```

But when i do these i can solve flickering but the interface load too slow and i wonder if there is any way to handle this?

Comment: Did you mean `WS_EX_COMPOSITED = 0x02000000,`, maybe? Try to first enable DoubleBuffering on the Form and see how it goes. Also, a CheckBox already inherits the background from its parent.

Comment: Yes i exactly mean that, that's a solution but i want to know if is there another way? Because this is not working exactly as i wanted. I still have to wait untill all controls load in the background, after all process done the form is showing.. This code is just make program smoother not faster..

Comment: Except you have set the wrong value: `0x02000000` != `0x02`. You should post the code you're referring to. I mean, if you add the controls at run-time. Also, if you have graphics rendering which may be triggered multliple times in the layout of the Form.